# Analogue of {% static %} in pure python

Tags: django

Django 3.0.6

Could you tell me whether there is a way to reverse static path outside any template?

For example, we have this:

```
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

**How can I write a python code to get such src?**

```
def example():
     img = "my_app/example.jpg"
     path = ...
     src = os.path.join(path, img)

     return src
```

It must work both locally and in the production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in static template tag does exactly this. It's a bit complex to dissect if you're new to writing template tags, but the cruft of it is this:

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

def static(path: str) -> str:
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
```